# Mapping and Interpolation

Tags: functions, interpolation

Does *Mathematica* have a mapping function like [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.4.x/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) or any of the [multidimensional ones](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)?

By this I mean something like mapping $[1,100]$ onto $[7,20]$ for example.

Looking at [Interpolate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) I only see interpolation with regards to estimating a line given points.

To make it more clear I mean a simple example using a linear mapping would be $[0,512]$ onto $[0,10]$ would give 5 for a value of 256.

Edited: (Comments added for greater precision):

1. What would make the question more clear? An example would be reading in a sensor that gives values on $[0,256]$ and using those to operate say a servo which accepts values on $[0,10]$
2. in this scale that is exactly what I'm looking for! thanks. Is it possible to use mappings of other orders, ex. a normal distribution or a quadratic mapping? This being a linear mapping. –

Comment: I don't understand what your asking for.

Comment: Do you mean splines? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Splines.html

Comment: Are you looking for `Rescale[256, {0,512}, {0,10}]` (==> 5)?

Comment: @BrettChampion in this scale that is exactly what I'm looking for! thanks. Is it possible to use mappings of other orders, ex. a normal distribution or a quadratic mapping? This being a linear mapping.

Comment: The reason why your question was unclear is that you mention interpolation when you need a linear transformation (they're unrelated) and that originally you didn't say at all that you need a *linear* transformation.   There are of course infinitely many (non-linear) mappings from interval $[a,b]$ to interval $[c,d]$.

Comment: Maybe you should clean up your question a bit. At the moment you appear to be asking first for interpolation, then for a rescaling

Answer (score 9):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you need the `Rescale` function, especially its 3 argument form:

```
Rescale[#, {1, 100}, {7, 20}] & /@ Range[1, 100, 5] // N
(* Out[1]= {7., 7.65657, 8.31313, 8.9697, 9.62626, 10.2828, 10.9394, 11.596, 12.2525, 12.9091, 
    13.5657, 14.2222, 14.8788, 15.5354, 16.1919, 16.8485, 17.5051, 18.1616, 18.8182, 19.4747}
 *)
```

Comment: what would make the question more clear? An example would be reading in a sensor that gives values on [0,256] and using those to operate say a servo which accepts values on [0,10].

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf Then `Rescale` is exactly what you want. You should also look into `Clip` to use along with this if you don't want to give out of bound values to your servo.

Comment: @R.M Rescale[] is what I thought about when reading the question, but I agree it wasn't evident. Author, you might want to edit your question adding the precisions you gave in the comments!